# Hard time selecting a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying to select a specific div in my DOM without success and I can't find what I am doing wrong. Can you help me please?

So here is my html code :

```
<div class="small" id="CV"><h1>Cliquez ici pour ouvrir mon CV</h1></div>
<div class="big" id="CVLarge">
  <!-- DOIT RESTER SOUS .big -->
  <img src="../Images/aPropos/fermer.png" alt="fermer" title="fermer">
  <h1>Diplômes</h1> <!-- etc etc-->
</div>
```

`.big` is `display:none` when the page loads.

There's a short jQuery code to open `.big` when you click `.small`. This one works fine.

```
$(".small").on("click", function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

The problems arises when I try to close `.big` by clicking on the cross button (the image alt:"fermer" in the html). I want it to hide `.big` and display `.small` again.

Here's my attempt :

```
$(".big img").on("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().closest(".small").fadeIn();
});
```

`.big` does toggle back to `display:none` but `.small` refuses to appear whatever I try.

To give you an idea of what I tried:

- A previous version of the jQuery to open `.big` used `replaceWith()` and I thought maybe it made `.small` disappear from the DOM thus not being able to appear again but even after I changed for a more "step by step" jQuery, the problem remains.
- I wonder if `closest()` only detects the parents of the element? But then I don't know how to get `.small` from "img".
- It works when I write `$("#CV")`, but I need this code to be less specific because the jQuery applies to several boxes with different id's.

Thank you for your attention. I am completely self taught so if I make obvious mistakes please point them out nicely (/ω＼)

Comment: You should always correctly indent, this will help you and the people reading your question to better understand your code. In your original formatting it looked like `.big`  is a child of `.small`, only on a closer look it was obvious that `.big` and `.small` are siblings. So if `.big` and `.small` are siblings, the `$(this).parent().closest(".small")` can't work, because this finds elements that are in a ascendant/descendant realtionship.

Comment: Thanks ! I will be careful to do this next time (￣^￣)ゞ

Answer (score 1):

Your selector for traversing to element with class small is wrong. You need to use `.prev()` selector instead of `.closest()` as its a sibling element to element with class big:

```
$(this).parent().prev(".small").fadeIn();
```

Comment: Oh my god it works it was so simple thank you so much T_T

Answer (score 0):

Try prev() instead of closest().

```
$(".big img").on("click", function(){
$(this).parent().slideToggle();
$(this).parent().prev().fadeIn();
});
```